# Custom query in angular-indexedDB

Tags: angularjs, indexeddb

I am using [bramski/angular-indexedDB](https://github.com/bramski/angular-indexedDB) in my application. Basic CRUD operations are working fine, but the custom queries are not working as expected. 
I am using the code

```
 angular.module('myModuleName', ['indexedDB'])
      .config(function ($indexedDBProvider) {
        $indexedDBProvider
          .connection('myIndexedDB')
          .upgradeDatabase(1, function(event, db, tx){
            var objStore = db.createObjectStore('people', {keyPath: 'ssn'});
            objStore.createIndex('name_idx', 'age', {unique: false});
            objStore.createIndex('name_idx, age_idx', ['name', 'age'] , {unique: false});
    });
```

Basic query operations are working like follows

```
$indexedDB.openStore('people', function(x){
   var find = x.query();
   find = find.$eq('John');
   find = find.$index("name_idx");    
   x.eachWhere(find).then(function(e){
      $scope.list= e;
   });
});
```

which results following query.

```
select * from people where name='John'
```

But, in the above scenario how we can execute custom quires like

```
select * from people where name='John' and age='25';
delete from people where name='John' and age='25';
```

Comment: looking at the source code for that provider, it appears the provider only performs queries against a single key.   It appears that you would have to modify the source of that provider and write your own multiple key query function, or write a filter on the client side to exclude the extra data.

Comment: Sorry, im new in indexeddb. Can't we fetch those details using the configured index combination? ie, objStore.createIndex('name_idx, age_idx', ['name', 'age'] , {unique: false});

Answer (score 0):

The library you are using doesn't have complex queries, however you can write a pure-js solution for it, similar to this:

First you need to define your index as:

```
objStore.createIndex('name_age_idx', ['name', 'age'] , {unique: false});
```

Then you can have a search query for only those values that match the search result

```js
searchIndexedDB = function (name, age, callback) {
  var request = indexedDB.open(dbName);
  request.onsuccess = function(e) {
    var db = e.target.result;
    var trans = db.transaction(objectStoreName, 'readonly');
    var store = trans.objectStore(objectStoreName);
    var index = store.index('name_age_idx');
    var keyRange = IDBKeyRange.only([name, age]);
    // open the index for all objects with the same name and age
    var openCursorRequest = index.openCursor(keyRange);

    openCursorRequest.onsuccess = function(e) {
        let result = e.target.result;
        // first check if value is found
        if(result){
            callback(result.value); // your callback will be called per object
            // result.delete() - to delete your object
            result.continue(); // to continue itterating - calls the next cursor request
        }
    };

    trans.oncomplete = function(e) {
        db.close();
    };

    openCursorRequest.onerror = function(e) {
        console.log("Error Getting: ", e);
    };
  };
  request.onerror = myStorage.indexedDB.onerror;
}
```

If you need a range from and too index, all you need is change the `keyrange` to:

```
var keyRange = IDBKeyRange.bound([name,fromAge], [value, toAge]);
```